# How to use db references with reactive Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and Reactor and I'm trying to retrieve a User with its Profiles associated
Here's the POJO :

```
public class User {

    private @Id String id;
    private String login;
    private String hashPassword;
    @Field("profiles") private List<String> profileObjectIds;
    @Transient private List<Profile> profiles; }

public class Profile {

    private @Id String id;
    private @Indexed(unique = true) String name;
    private List<String> roles; }
```

The problem is, how do I inject the profiles in the User POJO ?

I'm aware I can put a @DBRef and solve the problem but in it's documentation, MongoDB specify manual Ref should be preferred over DB ref.

I'm seeing two solutions :

1. Fill the pojo when I get it :

   ```
   public Mono<User> getUser(String login) {
       return userRepository.findByLogin(login)
       .flatMap(user -> ??? );
   }
   ```

I should do something with **profileRepository.findAllById()** but I don't know or to concatene both Publishers given that profiles result depends on user result.

2. Declare an AbstractMongoEventListener and override onAfterConvert method :

But here I am mistaken since the method end before the result is Published

```
public void onAfterConvert(AfterConvertEvent<User> event) {
    final User source = event.getSource();
    source.setProfiles(new ArrayList<>());
    profileRepository.findAllById(source.getProfileObjectIds())
    .doOnNext(e -> source.getProfiles().add(e))
    subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## TL;DR

There's no `DBRef` support in reactive Spring Data MongoDB and I'm not sure there will be.

## Explanation

Spring Data projects are organized into Template API, Converter and Mapping Metadata components. The imperative (blocking) implementation of the Template API uses an imperative approach to fetch `Document`s and convert these into domain objects. `MappingMongoConverter` in particular handles all the conversion and `DBRef` resolution. This API works in a synchronous/imperative API and is used for both Template API implementations (imperative and the reactive one).

Reuse of `MappingMongoConverter` was the logical decision while adding reactive support as we don't have a need to duplicate code. The only limitation is `DBRef` resolution that does not fit the reactive execution model.

To support reactive `DBRef`s, the converter needs to be split up into several bits and the whole association handling requires an overhaul.

Reference : https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2146

## Recommendation

Keep references as keys/Id's in your domain model and look up these as needed. `zipWith` and `flatMap` are the appropriate operators, depending on what you want to archive (enhance model with references, lookup references only).

On a related note: Reactive Spring Data MongoDB comes partially with a reduced feature set. Contextual SpEL extension is a feature that is not supported as these components assume an imperative programming model and thus synchronous execution.

Comment: The problem in this context is to attach converters to `ReactiveMongoTemplate` as `MappingMongoConverter` accepts `DefaultDbRefResolver`: `new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(new SimpleReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory(mongoClient, database)), new MongoMappingContext())`

Answer (score 6):

For the first point, I finally achieve doing what I wanted :

```
public Mono<User> getUser(String login) {
   return userRepository.findByLogin(login)
         .flatMap( user ->
              Mono.just(user)
              .zipWith(profileRepository.findAllById(user.getProfileObjectIds())
                  .collectionList(),
                  (u, p) -> {
                       u.setProfiles(p);
                       return u;
                   })
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have managed this problem using the follow approuch:

1. My Entity is:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "post")
public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6281811500337260230L;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Date date;
    private String title;
    private String body;
    private AuthorDto author;
    private Comment comment;
    private List<Comment> listComments = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> idComments = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

2. My controller is:

```
    @GetMapping(FIND_POST_BY_ID_SHOW_COMMENTS)
    @ResponseStatus(OK)
    public Mono<Post> findPostByIdShowComments(@PathVariable String id) {
        return postService.findPostByIdShowComments(id);
    }
```

3. Last, but not, least, my Service (here is the solution):

```
    public Mono<Post> findPostByIdShowComments(String id) {
        return postRepo
                .findById(id)
                .switchIfEmpty(postNotFoundException())
                .flatMap(postFound -> commentService
                                 .findCommentsByPostId(postFound.getId())
                                 .collectList()
                                 .flatMap(comments -> {
                                     postFound.setListComments(comments);
                                     return Mono.just(postFound);
                                 })
                        );
    }

    public Flux<Comment> findCommentsByPostId(String id) {
        return postRepo
                .findById(id)
                .switchIfEmpty(postNotFoundException())
                .thenMany(commentRepo.findAll())
                .filter(comment1 -> comment1.getIdPost()
                                            .equals(id));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this helped a lot.
Here is my solution:

```
public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter(MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext) {
    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(NoOpDbRefResolver.INSTANCE, mongoMappingContext);
    converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
    converter.setCustomConversions(mongoCustomConversions());
    return converter;
}
```

The trick was to use the NoOpDbRefResolver.INSTANCE