# User vs Role vs Scope modeling on Reactive MongoDB

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-mongodb

I'm writing an authorization server POC using the reactive version of MongoDB. Firstly, it seems that the `@DBRef` annotation does not work reactively, neither there will be support for it, which was my initial problem as I would like to create "relations" between the three models. So:

1. Is "manual relations" really the only way to achieve this?
2. In real world scenarios, is it recommended to store the roles as enum values instead of database?

Reference: [Reactive `@DBRef`: manual relations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50078429/5446775)

Comment: in real world scenarios i would recommend using a relational database if you have the need for relationships, and not a document database.

Comment: i read a bit more, MonoDB themselfes write in their documentation that they recommend manual references `Unless you have a compelling reason to use DBRefs, use manual references instead.` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/ and spring themselves write `I don't think DBRef resolution will happen anytime soon. In fact, we try to avoid this feature as MongoDB recommends manual references.` https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2146 as written before, mongoDB is a document database its not built for relationships.